# Difficulty loading large dataframes from S3 jsonl data into glue for conversion to parquet: Memory Constraints and failed worker spawning

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I am attempting to load large datasets from S3 in JSONL format using AWS glue. The S3 data is accessed through a glue table projection. Once they are loaded, I save them back to a different S3 location in Parquet format. For the most part this strategy works, but for some of my datasets, the glue job runs out of memory. On closer inspection, it would seem it is trying to load the entire large dataset onto one executor before redistributing it.

I have tried upgrading the worker size to G.1X from standard so that it would have more memory and CPU, and this did not work for me: the script would still crash.

It was recommended I try the techniques for partitioning input data outlined on this page:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/grouping-input-files.html

I tried to use the groupSize and groupFiles parameters, but these did not work for me: the script would still crash.

Finally, I was recommended to set `--config` options like in a typical spark environment so that my program could use more memory, but as I am working in AWS I am not able to set the config.

The following code demonstrates what I'm attempting to do:

```py
    datasource = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
        database=SOURCE_GLUE_DATABASE, 
        table_name=SOURCE_TABLE
    )

    # yapf: disable
    glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        frame=datasource,
        connection_type="s3",
        connection_options={
            "path": OUTPUT_PATH,
        },
        format="parquet"
    )
```

The expected result ( and the one I see for most of my datasets ) is that parquet data is written out to the new S3 location. In the worst cases, looking through the logs reveals that only one worker is being used, despite having set the maximum capacity setting for the job to 10 or more. It seems that it just doesn't want to create more workers, and I can't understand why.

Comment: it seems your data has skewness.

Comment: Have you tried repartitioning your data before writing it out to s3?